# Which type of curly brace coding style is better for java programmers?

Tags: java, coding-style, curly-braces

I have seen in many tutorials , some programmers uses curly braces in same line with code , others use curly braces in separate line , and rest uses mixed approach .

So my question is , Should curly braces be on their own line or not?

```
if (you.hasAnswer()) {
    you.postAnswer();
} else {
    you.doSomething();
}
```

or should it be

```
if (you.hasAnswer())
{
    you.postAnswer();
}
else
{
    you.doSomething();
}
```

or even

```
if (you.hasAnswer()){
    you.postAnswer();
}
else{
    you.doSomething();
}
```

In Oracle official [site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-142311.html#431) about code convention , they given code like this

```
if (condition) {
    statements;
}

if (condition) {
    statements;
} else {
    statements;
}

if (condition) {
    statements;
} else if (condition) {
    statements;
} else {
    statements;
}
```

Comment: Whatever you like the most. Normally the coding conventions of the language is used.

Comment: I prefer the second style - but it all comes down what the coding convention of your *team* are.

Comment: What religion is better for programmers? Islam or Christianity?

Comment: Follow the code that's already there. If there's none already there, choose your favourite (and that unfortunately makes the question a subjective one). My fave is the first one since I like to see as much code as possible on the screen at once.

Comment: If it make any difference in compiler level ?

Comment: @SujithPS No absolutely not. Compiler does not care about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First or third. I favour the first for compactness mostly, but in "if else" trees sometimes use the third for 'syntactical simplicity' of commenting lines in/out.

Vertical space is valuable, since research finds the comprehension limit of an algorithm is closely related to the vertical size that can be seen on one screen. Wasting vertical space with extra lines for unimportant if-branches is pointless.

Comment: I find the second style easier to read/follow than the first one because the blocks are "lined up" (due to the fact that the opening and the closing bracket are on the same level)

Comment: Code comprehension is more of a challenge when there's _a lot_ of it, than for a trivial single `if`. So that's the case we have to target our style guidelines towards. I believe there's an objective & factual basis for judgement here.